# Aspas dentro de aspas para enviar parametro string

Tags: php

A linha de código PHP abaixo deve ser exibida no site e é chamada utilizando JavaScript.

```
        echo "
        <div class='tipoPagamento' onclick='SelecionarTipoPagamento({$row['CODIGO']}, '{$row['TIPO']}');'>
            <font color='#fff'>
                <h4 style='margin-top: -15px;'>{$row['ESPECI']}</h4>
            </font>
        </div>
    ";
```

Na segunda linha, na tag div.. tenho chamar a função 'SelecionarTipoPagamento(int, str)'.
Como indiquei, ela tem um parametro inteiro e outro string.. por isso coloco a variável $row['TIPO'] entre aspas. Porém a função não está sendo chamada, pois está com erro.

Removendo o parametro da string tudo funciona bem e o código fica assim:

```
            echo "
        <div class='tipoPagamento' onclick='SelecionarTipoPagamento({$row['CODIGO']});'>
            <font color='#fff'>
                <h4 style='margin-top: -15px;'>{$row['ESPECI']}</h4>
            </font>
        </div>
    ";
```

Creio que eu não esteja sabendo utilizar as aspas corretamente, porém pelo que vi na internet está correto... o que seria o erro?

Estou usando os seguintes scripts: (estou especificando pois ouvi falar que alguns não aceitam aspas simples ou algo assim)

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/database.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.poptrox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mask.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-wide.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-normal.css" />
    </noscript>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
```

A função 'SelecionarTipoPagamento()' é esta:

```
function SelecionarTipoPagamento(cod, tipo){
alert("oi");
alert(cod);
alert(tipo);
codTipoPagamento = cod;}
```

Answer (score 4):

Já resolvi o problema, após muito pensar percebi que o problema não está no php em si, mas na string que o HTML executa, pois o HTML ficaria assim:

```
onclick='funcao('str');'
```

E isso gera aspas simples dentro de aspas simples, pra funcionar então o código ficou:

```
echo "
        <div class='tipoPagamento' onclick=\"SelecionarTipoPagamento({$row['CODIGO']}, '{$row['TIPO']}');\">
            <font color='#fff'>
                <h4 style='margin-top: -15px;'>{$row['ESPECI']}</h4>
            </font>
        </div>
    ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Fecha as aspas na função e depois abre de novo.
Realmente, esse pode ser o erro.

```
echo "<div class='tipoPagamento' onclick='".SelecionarTipoPagamento($row['CODIGO'])."'>
            <font color='#fff'>
                <h4 style='margin-top: -15px;'>{$row['ESPECI']}</h4>
            </font>
        </div>
    ";
```

Comment: Não funcionou.. parece que ele chama a função ao invés de geral o HTML com a string... já que retorna o erro:

"Call to undefined function SelecionarTipoPagamento() in ... "